# Non trivial examples of open subsets that satisfy these conditions

Tags: general-topology

I have these following sets (the overbar means closure)
[image]

[image]

This doesn't work with open intervals such as $(a,b)$ or $(c,d)$ because at least two of these sets are equal. But I can't think of open subsets that satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=(0, 2)\cup(3,4)$ and $B=(1, 3)$. Then

$$A\cap \overline{B}=[1, 2)$$
$$\overline{A}\cap B=(1, 2]$$
$$\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=[1, 2]\cup\{3\}$$
$$\overline{A\cap B}=[1, 2]$$

Comment: I wasn't sure about the closure of the union of open intervals. If the closure of $(a,b)$ is $[a,b]$ then the closure of $(a,b)\cap(c,d)$ is $[a,b]\cap[c,d]$?

Comment: @math4everyone Closure of the union is always equal to the union of closures. So for $\cup$ yes, but not for $\cap$.